A Hollywood movie about a popcorn boy challenge dancing competition
I need a dancing-based movie's name, in which one popcorn boy challenges a high-level dance group.
Popcorn boy and one other boy search for a dancer around the world, a different kind of dancer. One day, popcorn boy goes in a bar. There he finds one girl with a high level of dancing. His group and the bar's dance group have a challenge and then the girl is ready for competition.
In the final dance competition they come late, they enter as popcorn seller and challenge dancer. In the last round that girl comes and gives a super performance and wins the dance competition.
It's a Hollywood movie in English movies and is the second part. Both parts are based on dancing and were released a few years ago.

I think I know what you're after, but can you please provide some basic details like country\language, year and anything else you might remember?

This is Hollywood, English movies. I thin this is second part. Both part is based on dancing.. In staring on this movies one pop-corn boy fall in floor and all throw pop-corn on him.. Then he decided to challenge that dance group.. And he and his manager start finding dancer around the world, they get and robot dancer couple, and thief, etc, and promise them to win dance computation..

Was it a recent movie?

No, It is not recent movie.. Both part released in few year ago. I just forgot its name.

A few years ago is still pretty recent in my book. ;) Edited & posting a possible match.

Sounds like StreetDance 2 from 2012.

Beaten by his rival Invincible's hip-hop crew and ridiculed as 'Popcorn boy', Ash seeks revenge at the annual international street dance championship in Paris. He travels trough Europe to gather an exceptionally talented crew. In Paris, he meets in her overprotective uncle-guardian Manu's bar and wants Latin dancer Eva. They agree to attempt a fusion with hip-hop, introducing Latin pair dancing, and become lovers.

It was the sequel to StreetDance 3D from 2010. Here's the trailer:



